# Bootstrap linking to DOM element working on one button but not another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

First question here!

Basically I'm using Bootstrap, trying to use a button to link to another element on the page. I use it on one button and it works, but I use a Google Maps InfoWindow to create a new button that doesn't work. I have no idea what the difference is (other than one being added on top of the map using JQuery, but this one also changes the URL of the page!)

EDIT: The button on the InfoWindow shows up correctly and everything.

Here's the code!

JQUERY

```
var contentString = '<a class="portfolio-item d-block mx-auto" href="#create-report">\n' +
    '                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">\n' +
    '                    Reportar ocorrência\n' +
    '                </button>\n' +
    '            </a>';

var latLng = e.latLng;

if(infowindow != null)
    infowindow.close();

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    position: latLng
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="portfolio-modal mfp-hide" id="create-report">
<div class="portfolio-modal-dialog bg-white">
    <a class="close-button d-none d-md-block portfolio-modal-dismiss" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-times"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                <h2 class="text-secondary text-uppercase mb-0">Reportar Ocorrência</h2>
                <hr class="star-dark mb-5">
                <form name="newReport" id="reportForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                            <label>Nome da Ocorrência</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="reportName" type="text" placeholder="Nome da Ocorrência*" required="required"
                                   data-validation-required-message="Insira o nome da ocorrência.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                            <label>Localização</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="reportAddress" type="text"
                                   placeholder="Localização (morada, por exemplo)*" required="required"
                                   data-validation-required-message="Insira a localização da ocorrência.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                            <label>Descrição</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="reportDescription" type="text" placeholder="Descrição*"
                                   required="required" data-validation-required-message="Insira a descrição da ocorrência.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="successReport"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" id="reportBtn">Reportar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <br>
                <a id="closeFormBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg rounded-pill portfolio-modal-dismiss" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>Fechar
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.portfolio {
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-width: 25rem;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-caption {
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(175, 49, 16, 0.8);
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-caption:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-caption .portfolio-item-caption-content {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .portfolio {
    margin-bottom: -30px;
  }
  .portfolio .portfolio-item {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

.portfolio-modal .portfolio-modal-dialog {
  padding: 3rem 1rem;
  height: calc(100vh - 6rem);
  min-height: 850px;
  margin: 1rem calc(1rem - 8px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.portfolio-modal .portfolio-modal-dialog .close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
}

.portfolio-modal .portfolio-modal-dialog .close-button i {
  line-height: 38px;
}

.portfolio-modal .portfolio-modal-dialog h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .portfolio-modal .portfolio-modal-dialog {
    height: calc(100vh - 6rem);
    min-height: 850px;
    padding: 5rem;
    margin: 3rem calc(3rem - 8px);
  }
  .portfolio-modal .portfolio-modal-dialog h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So Instead of
'\n' + ' \n' + ' Reportar ocorrência\n' + ' \n'

You need to use that style for the modal button trigger

```
   <!-- Button trigger modal --> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"> Launch demo modal </button>
```

And that for the div for the modl

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but that's not the issue! I'm trying to open a Bootsrap modal when I click the button on the infowindow. The infowindow itself opens up fine!

Comment: I have updated the answer, i think you just miss the attributes for the modal and modal button trigger

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the answer! I have tried using those tags and they give me some conflicts (mostly visually but also functionally). The thing is I have another anchor, exactly the same and that one works, but that one is static on the page.

Comment: <a class="portfolio-item d-block mx-auto" href="#create-report">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xl btn-outline-light">
                    Reportar ocorrência
                </button>
            </a>